Aggregation sorting based on either of 1 key in open search
Consider below is the 2 documents got after aggregation , now i need to sort on the documents.
Document 1:
{
'startDate' :'2023-02-01',
'endDate' : '2022-02-01'
}

Documet 2 :
{
'endDate' : '2024-02-01'
}

Now i should receive the 2nd document as result after sorting.
Below is the query i am using
{
    "groupBy-top-hits": {
        "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
                {
                    "startDate": {
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "endDate": {
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "size": 1
        }
    }
}

But its returning the 1st document. Query should be if either of the key is present use that for sorting, but its not working that way. Suggest if any query needs to be changed.

When the sort expression includes multiple fields, sorting is primarily based on the first field. Only if there are identical values in the first field (in your case, startDate) will the second field be considered. By default, missing values are sorted last. Therefore, because the startDate of the first document is higher than the startDate of the second document (which is absent and therefore sorted as last), the first document appears in the results.
